# Pushup strength decreasing after joining Gym?

Tags: push-ups

I started doing pushups only. I reached a maximum of 30 at one time and then squeezed in around 100 pushups every day. This was going on for a few months.

Then I joined a gym. I do a full-body workout every other day and, for the sake of rest for the body, I don't do any exercise on the non-workout days.

The problem is that I am not able to do as many pushups now as I could before joining the gym.

*Q1: What could be the reason?* 
*Q2: Should I do pushups every day and squeeze in 100 in a day no matter what?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in addition to doing pushups, you're now doing exercises that exhaust your chest, tricep, and deltoid muscles. Either you're muscles are recovering or just sore.

Also are you doing sets of pushups? I know you said a max of 30 but a 100 a day.. like 3 sets of 30 and 1 set of 10.. or do you do 100 pushups throughout the day as you see fit?

I will say there are a LOT of better chest exercises than pushups so if you are in a gym just do your chest workout there with weights, whether your goal is endurance or strength.

After 30 pushups(funny how this is your maximum) your muscles quit getting a benefit far as getting bigger or stronger.. meaning doing 40 or 50 pushups wont build muscular endurance and this more goes into cardio.. Id say unless you are doing a cardio circuit to burn fat or condition, feel free to give up pushups altogether. They are great cardio but unless you are putting a plate on your back they are too easy for other goals like strength or endurance

Comment: I use to do 100 pushups throughout the day as I see fit. I was an obese person weighing 110 Kgs, who lost 16 kgs in last 6 months. Thats why 30 was my maximum. I think the fitter you are the more pushups you can do. Why do you think my 30 max is funny?

Comment: because your maximum is also when pushups start to become cardio. not really funny so much as youre starting to see the dividing line between the two in your workout. Fitness cannot be qualified by trivial means such as how many pushups one can do... youre losing weight because youre doing cardio with 100 pushups. I was saying that they arent the best exercise for strength or hypertrophy once you go past 30 in a single set. By all means do pushups to burn fat... if your goals are to build muscle there are better and quicker ways to achieve your goals.

Comment: got it now, all I want to do is lose weight now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you gained any weight after gym ? 
If yes , that could be one of the reason.

The main factor here will be "Muscle soreness" or [DOMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness). After your full body workouts your muscle needs time to repair itself and get stronger but while it is recovering it might not be as strong as it used to be.You don't have to squeeze out 100 push-ups every day just leave some time to recover and you will do fine.

You're in a beginner level program , just do push ups everyday before workout and once when your body gets adapted you could go back to your 100 push-ups a day routine.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot sit on two chairs with one ass. If you add exercise/skill to your practice, you sacrifice something else.

If you want to be great at pushups, you should train only skills that assist the pushup. If you want to train full-body properly, be ready, your pushups will drop.

Unrelated note 1: I have never seen anyone do more than 20 **strict** pushups. I am not saying that everyone should do them super strict, but do not fool yourself with fake improvements.

Unrelated note 2: If you can do more than 10-20 pushups, it is not about the strength that much.